# Chromebook Linux hardware issues

Tags: linux-mint, hardware, chrome-book, fan

I recently upgraded my Chromebook Falco to a 128GB SSD and put Linux Mint on it. I'm really happy I did it, but I've noticed that my fan is running constantly. Is there something I can do to help the fan from running less, or am I just going to have to live with this?

Comment: The fan doesn't drain your battery, but it indicates heavy load on CPU or GPU which does. Are there some processes taking lots of resources?

Comment: Opening the system monitor, it doesn't show any background processes running, but shows CPU 1 and 2 running between 3-6%. I'm thinking that there may be a gap between the hardware and software, which is causing the older hardware to constantly run in order to keep up with the software.

Comment: Check your sensors, maybe something is overheating your laptop. If not, you could/should find a way to change the fan algorithms, maybe you can do it only in the BIOS (EFI).

Comment: after running the program watch sensors, it tells me i'm running between 30 and 40 degrees Celsius. After doing some research it seems normal, but I just want to make sure that it is normal